# Возникает ошибка, при попытке установить любой плагин

Tags: sublime-text

при попытке установить любой плагин - выдает эту ошибку. Можете помочь? 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пишут, что эта ошибка вызвана нестандартными настройками соединения в IE. Проще всего зайти в IE и сделать сброс настроек. IE>Свойства обозревателя>Дополнительно и жмем кнопку Сброс

Comment: Нет, не помогло

Comment: Может вам провайдер гитхаб заблокировал?

Comment: Соединение может блочить файрвол и антивирус. Также протокол https может не работать из за неправильных настроек времени и даты.